# cURL redirect causing error

Tags: php, curl

I am currently trying to curl a form with method=GET.  I have the complete link with the data on the end of the url.  If I place the link directly into the address bar it works.  When I curl the link it gives me an "Object not found!" error and changes the address bar URL to http://localhost/ocs?name=mike.

I believe I have a similar problem to this question but I am unsure what the solution to this question was:
[Curl Redirect Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646263/curl-redirect-problem)

Code I currently have:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url = "http://www.example.com/ocs?name=mike";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $data;
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You may try setting the curl options "CURL_FOLLOWOCATION" and "CURL_MAXREDIRS". These will allow your CURL request to follow the redirects of the destination url.

Comment: I just tried  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); but it still did the same thing.

Comment: Dont know which url you are trying to fetch...but curl_error & curl_errno may give you an insight of whats going on.